How to schedule a job to run if the previous day was a working day (based on a calendar) in Control M?
I haven't been able to figure out how to shcedule a job to run only if the previous day was a working day.
Can someone help me out with this?
Thanks!
I have tried to use the confirmation calendar but I still could not do it

Do you mean Tuesday to Saturday? That's fairly easy to schedule. Or do you need to take into account public holidays?

Yes, it would be taking into account holidays. For instance, if today were a holiday then the process should not run tomorrow (which is a business day) but it should run today (because yesterday was a business day).
